# Why does the Croatia-Euro to USD exchange rate differ from the Eurozone-Euro to USD exchange rate in the list of Treasury reporting rate of exchange?

Tags: euro-area

Looking at the [list of Treasury reporting rate of exchange](https://fiscaldata.treasury.gov/datasets/treasury-reporting-rates-exchange/treasury-reporting-rates-of-exchange), I see that the Croatia-Euro to USD exchange rate (`0.925`) differ from the Eurozone-Euro to USD exchange rate (`0.936`). Why?

[image]

Comment: They have different effective dates (scroll right on the table in your link).  The EuroZone-Euro figure of 0.936 is for 12/31/2022 (like almost all of the other rates) while the Croatia-Euro figure of 0.925 is for 1/13/2023.  The USD-EUR rates vary over time and what you have seen simply reflects the timing difference and the US Treasury being a little slow in spotting Croatia had adopted the Euro

Comment: @Henry thanks, my bad, good catch! Didn't see the other columns.